# How to Display Contact List in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I want to create contact list similar to this picture below ,along with the indication of alphabet appears on scrolling the contact list.

[image: Contact list]

Please help me how to do this or any reference link.

Answer (score 1):

You can do some thng like this :

```
Contacts contacts = new Contacts();
contacts.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<ContactsSearchEventArgs>(contacts_SearchCompleted);
contacts.SearchAsync(String.Empty, FilterKind.DisplayName,null);
```

then you can access properties of contacts to get what you want

Comment: i want the scrolling Alphabet indication on scrolling list

Comment: as you have acollection of elements you can sort them alphabetically and use long listselector to help you in view them check this link : http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/the-new-longlistselector-control-in-windows-phone-8-sdk-in-depth

Comment: thanks for link. i have used it earlier but now i am trying to indicate alphabet on scrolling the list near the contact list.and the nearest alphabet is appears.

Comment: I think you are doing it wrong, Windows Phone is not Android.